# How to transpose a text data with visual studio C#

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a txt file that is pure data(no mark-up language) like this：

```
A 3 8 7
d E 9 S
```

now I need to use Visual studio C# to load it and transpose this into another txt file like:

```
A d
3 E
8 9
7 S
```

all the partition are TAB not space

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why use XSLT if it's not XML?!

Comment: I'm using XSLT to transfer a complicated XML into a pure data XML, but I need to transpose the result, so I'm thinking use another XSLT to do it

Comment: Transpose it in the XSLT you already have.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to complicate my question, so I need to know how to do it first, then I can add the method to my origin XSLT

Comment: This makes no sense. A file that is "pure data(no mark-up language)" is not XML and cannot be transformed by XSLT (at least not XSLT 1.0).

Comment: i'm sorry for my ignorance and thanks for the information, so I'm now editing my question.

Comment: The question now seems to be easy now , maybe i can figure out myself, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in XQuery 3.1:

```
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";
let $in := unparsed-text-lines('test.txt') ! array{tokenize(.)}
return fold-left(tail($in), head($in), array:for-each-pair(?, ?,         
         function($x, $y){$x || ' ' || $y}))?* => string-join('&#xa;')
```

The bulk of this is pure XPath 3.1, so you can integrate it into an XSLT stylesheet if that's what you want to do.

How does it work?

First read the lines of the input file, and tokenize each line to create $in as a sequence of arrays containing the lines of the input.

Then for each pair of rows in turn, concatenate the corresponding pairs of members to create a space-separated string. With the array of strings that results, first convert to a sequence of strings (using "?*"), then join the strings in this sequence with newline as a separator.

You can run this from C# by installing Saxon (needs Saxon-PE or higher).